# Link Boost headers without -I flag ( MinGW Distro from nuwen.net )

Tags: boost, g++, mingw, compiler-flags

I Have **MinGW Distro** with GCC comiler and Boost Libs (download from [nuwen.net](https://nuwen.net/mingw.html)).

I need link some Boost  headers. And GCC don't looking for headers in `"C:\MinGW\include"` folder. It looking for only in this folders:

```
g++ ./server.cpp -v -c 
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../include/c++/8.1.0
 c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../include/c++/8.1.0/x86_64-w64-mingw32
 c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../include/c++/8.1.0/backward
 c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include
 c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include-fixed
 c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include
End of search list.
```

In my makefile I have to do this

```
g++ -I "C:\MinGW\include" ./main.cpp
```

but I want do just this:

```
g++ ./main.cpp
```

Can I set some Windows 10 evironment variable for gcc or I need set gcc it-self or something like this?
Or should I always wirte flag `-I` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.
I have to compile it in the command line, which is opened by the file `C:\MinGW\open_distro_window.bat`. As stated in the instructions, in the third paragraph on these site.